# jqgrid did not display any field on edit or add form

Tags: jqgrid, row, addition

I built a very basic jqgrid table.  It displays results from the url I provide without problems.  If I click on add row or on edit row icon, an empty windows appears without any fields to fill.

Here is my code:

```
$('#mygrid').jqGrid({  
        colMenu: true,
        url: 'someurl.php',
        datatype:'json',
        colNames:['NUMB','ACCNAME','MEMO','TOTAL','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC','JAN','FEB','MAR'],
        colModel: [
            { name: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER",  width:60},
            { name: "ACCNAME",  editable: "true"},
            { name: "DETAIL",  editable: "true", edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "TOTAL",  width:75, classes:'text-primary', editable: "true",editoptions:{size:10}  },
            { name: "APR", index: "APR",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "MAY", index: "MAY",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "JUN", index: "JUN",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "JUL", index: "JUL",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "AUG", index: "AUG",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "SEP", index: "SEP",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "OCT",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "NOV",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "DEC",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "JAN",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "FEB",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10} },
            { name: "MAR",  width:75, editable: "true",edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{size:10}  }

        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
        rowNum: 15,
        styleUI : 'Bootstrap4',
        iconSet : 'Octicons',
        pager : '#gridpager',
        autowidth : true, 
        shrinkToFit : false,
        height : '75%',
        rowList : [10, 20, 30],
        altRows : true,
        toppager : true,
        caption: "something",
        editurl : 'anotherurl.php'


});
$("#mygrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{add:true,edit:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true});
```

Here the empty windows that pop-up:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser's console? And if so, can you expose them here? I'm new to this so I'm not sure if my question applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you have is with setting the editable property. You set it as string, but it should be a boolean. In colModel items replace

```
editable : "true"
```

with

```
editable : true
```

This is a big difference in Javascript

Comment: My, o my ... What a dummy mistake i did :)

Comment: You sometime passing a lot of time in little mistake like this. THANK YOU TONY !!

Comment: Not a problem @tompasto Glad to help.